# What book is the "Everything in the Book" power from?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers

Please see above. I think it's a daily that make an attack on all of a targets defenses AC, Fort Ref and Will?

Comment: On a side note, you can always use the [4e Compendium](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/database.aspx) to look up what book something is from, even if you don't have DDI.

Comment: @ObliviousSage Unless it is from Multiple Sources. :( Then you need DDI to find out what those sources are.

Answer (score 10):

You're thinking of the power "Every Trick in the Book". It's the level 20 daily associated with the Jack-of-All-Trades paragon path, which is from the Martial Power 2 book.